# PHP array to specified json structure

Tags: php, json, foreach

I need to get an JSON structure as following:

```
{
   "emails": [
        {
            "sender": "shihas@abc.com",
            "unread_count": 2,
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": "89",
                    "email": "shihas@abc.com",
                    "read": "0",
                },
                {
                    "id": "32",
                    "email": "shihas@abc.com",
                    "read": "0",
                }
            ]
       },
       {
            "sender": "marias123@gmail.com",
            "unread_count": 0,
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "email": "marias123@gmail.com",
                    "read": "1",
                }
            ]
       },
       {
            "sender": "gutar4320@hotmail.com",
            "unread_count": 1,
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "email": "gutar4320@hotmail.com",
                    "read": "0",
                }
            ]
       }
   ]
}
```

**Array($hire_email):**

In the below array I need to group all the details based on the `email`. And also count the no. of unread messages(i.e read = 0).

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 89
        [email] => shihas@abc.com
        [read] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 32
        [email] => shihas@abc.com
        [read] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [email] => marias123@gmail.com
        [read] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [email] => gutar4320@hotmail.com
        [read] => 0
    )
)
```

The following is the code snippet used for maintaining the JSON structure.

```
foreach($hire_email as $val) {
    if($val['read']==0){ $count++; }else{ $count = 0;}
    $hire_group_email[$val['email']]['sender'] = $val['email'];
    $hire_group_email[$val['email']]['unread_count'] = $count;
    $hire_group_email[$val['email']]['items'][] = $val;
}
$output["emails"][] = $hire_group_email;
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: if read is 0, the message wasn't read right? if its 1, the message was already read?

Comment: @TK Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
$hire_email =array(
    array(
        "id" => "89",
        "email" => "shihas@abc.com",
        "read" => "0"
    ),

    array
        (
            "id" => "32",
            "email" => "shihas@abc.com",
            "read" => "0"
        ),

    array
        (
            "id" => "2",
            "email" => "marias123@gmail.com",
            "read" => "1"
        ),

    array
        (
            "id" => "1",
            "email" => "gutar4320@hotmail.com",
            "read" => "0"
        )
);
$tmp = array();

foreach($hire_email as $arg)
{
    $tmp[$arg['email']][] = $arg;
}

$output = array();

foreach($tmp as $type => $labels)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($labels as $value) {
        if($value['read']==0){ $count++; }else{ $count = 0;}
    }
    $output[] = array(
        'sender' => $type,
        'unread_count' => $count,
        'items' => $labels
    );
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: This is perfect and thank you so much dude. But as you are using 3 `foreach` in this solution, its taking little time for large array. Is there any alternative solution for this?

Comment: Welcome bro. and i know i used 3 foreach. Let me check again and will send you another solution if possible.

Comment: Sure. Appreciated for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this, using: [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), the rest is just picking out the first items values.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true)['emails'];

$result = [];
foreach($array as $val) {
    $result[] = [
        'id' => $val['items'][0]['id'],
        'email' => $val['items'][0]['email'],
        'read' => array_sum(array_column($val['items'], 'read'))
    ];
}

$output["emails"] = $result;

echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "emails": [
        {
            "id": "89",
            "email": "shihas@abc.com",
            "read": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "email": "marias123@gmail.com",
            "read": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "email": "gutar4320@hotmail.com",
            "read": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

https://3v4l.org/hi7qm

And if you want it as shown ;p (my mistake, misread it):

Loop over each item, then loop over the `items` and use that to build the output.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true)['emails'];

$result = [];
foreach($array as $val) {
    foreach ($val['items'] as $item) {
        $result[] = [
            'id' => $item['id'],
            'email' => $item['email'],
            'read' => array_sum(array_column($val['items'], 'read'))
        ];
    }
}

$output["emails"] = $result;

echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "emails": [
        {
            "id": "89",
            "email": "shihas@abc.com",
            "read": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "32",
            "email": "shihas@abc.com",
            "read": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "email": "marias123@gmail.com",
            "read": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "email": "gutar4320@hotmail.com",
            "read": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

https://3v4l.org/eU95A

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the result is not as expected structure.

Comment: No worries, it looks the same to me (second version), update your question with how you want it to look.

Comment: The required JSON structure is in the top. In your result the `items` are not there.